# complex function bounded from below: meaning?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm working on a problem from complex Analysis. And I try to get a broader understanding of the problem (and complex analysis in general)

In the problem, where I have to prove that there exists an integer C, such that for all z on the contour N of a square, $|\sin z| \geq C$.

The solution is that we can bound $|\sin z|$ from below by $C = 1$.

But what does this mean?

I know that by definition of boundedness, a function f(x) is bounded from below if $f(x) \geq k$ for some number k.

But what does it mean in the context of complex numbers and the complex plane? Is complex numbers generally "bigger" than real numbers? Is there something you can recommend me reading up on?

Hope you can help with your expertise and that my questions makes sense.

Comment: The modulus of a complex number is a real number, and so it makes sense to say that the modulus of a complex valued function is bounded below (it is always bounded below by 0, but I suppose you want something better than that in your problem).